# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, css, html5, веб-программирование, файлы

Всем привет, мне нужно прочитать txt файл, и напечатать его в консоль и textarea.
При попытке вылезает ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

html:

```js
function openfile(input) {
  let file = input.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  let text = reader.result;
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(text);
    document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = reader.result;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none;" onclick="openfile(this)" accept=".txt" />
<a onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Open</a>
<textarea id="ta" placeholder="Write something here..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать на  `input` событие `onchange`.

```js
function openfile(input) {
  let file = input.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    let text = reader.result;
    console.log(text);
    document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = text;
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="openfile(this)" accept=".txt" />
<a onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Open</a>
<textarea id="ta" placeholder="Write something here..."></textarea>
```